# How to configure apt-get in Debian Stable, Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Tags: debian, apt-get

I am using Stable Debian (8.1 - jessie), installed from [Live (debian-live-8.1.0-amd64-xfce-desktop.iso)](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/)...

Now, starting to install all other things, nothing is possible (!)... `apt-get` and *Synaptic* not working...

- with `apt-get install apache2`: "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)", "E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?".
- with *Synaptic* interface: mark `apache2`, ... When I press [apply] it says, at alert, "Could not apply changes, Fix broken packages first".

---

NOTES

I am logged with `root` in the descktop interface, and do (with no error alert) all the suggested updates,

```
 apt-get update
 apt-get upgrade
 apt-get dist-upgrade
 apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No terrible problem... Was `/etc/apt/sources.list`, it needs to comment old and add new

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20150606-15:13]/ jessie main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20150606-15:13]/ jessie main

#lixio deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
#lixo deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

deb http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```